# Countable union of measure $0$ sets has measure $0$

Tags: measure-theory

I want to ask if it is true in general topological space that the countable union of sets of measure $0$ has $0$ measure?

Comment: It is true in general *measure spaces* as a consequence of countable additivity.

Comment: On the other hand, a countable union of *meager sets* is meager, in any topological space (meager means it is a countable union of nowhere dense subsets). Meager sets are the usual notion of "negligible" in the context of topological spaces, while "contained in a set of measure zero" is the usual notion of "negligible" in measure spaces.

Answer (score 12):

A general topological space doesn't have a notion of "measure 0".

The statement you ask about is true in a general *measure space*.  By definition, measures are required to be countably additive.  This means that
$$
m\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i\right) \;=\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty m(S_i)
$$
for any countable disjoint collection of measurable sets $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$.  As a consequence, if $\{S_i\}_{i=1}^\infty$ is *any* countable collection of measurable sets (not necessarily disjoint), then
$$
m\left(\bigcup_{i=1}^\infty S_i\right) \;\leq\; \sum_{i=1}^\infty m(S_i)
$$
In particular, if each $S_i$ has measure $0$, then the union must also have measure $0$.

Answer (score 3):

"Measure" doesn't make sense in a general topological space. In a general [measure space](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_%28mathematics%29), a countable union of measure-zero sets always has measure zero, by the countable subadditivity of measures.